# Is it possible to prohibit the use of SSL Version 3.0 on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

if the application is connected in SSL3.0, I do not want to display any page.
I am learner of English and GAE.
If English is hard to understand , I'm sorry .

Answer (score 2):

It seems the Google security team has already taken the necessary steps.

According to their [recent security bulletin](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/security-bulletins),

> App Engine, Cloud Storage, BigQuery, and CloudSQL customers do not need to take any actions. Google’s servers have been updated and are protected from this vulnerability. Customers of Compute Engine need to update their OS images.

I am not sure exactly what that means, but presumably SSLv3 fallback connections are disabled now.

**Update**

Okay, apparently they did not disable SSLv3 completely, but provide a more secure fallback. From [a blog post](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.sg/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html)

> Disabling SSL 3.0 support, or CBC-mode ciphers with SSL 3.0, is sufficient to mitigate this issue, but presents significant compatibility problems, even today. Therefore **our recommended response is to support TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV.** This is a mechanism that solves the problems caused by retrying failed connections and thus prevents attackers from inducing browsers to use SSL 3.0. It also prevents downgrades from TLS 1.2 to 1.1 or 1.0 and so may help prevent future attacks.
>
> Google Chrome and **our servers have supported TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV since February** and thus we have good evidence that it can be used without compatibility problems

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to research, but It can not seem to be completely disable use of SSL v3.